# Migrate from OS X Lion Developer Preview 3 to Public Release

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I am currently running Mac OS X Lion Developer Preview 3 and would like to install the recent public release version. Any ideas on how this can be done?

When I go to purchase Lion in the Mac App store, it says 'Installed'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal route Apple wants you to take is to start from a fresh installation. I guess this has always been the case and is most probably mentioned in the terms of the Developer Previews. Not too sure though, since I've never run a Developer version.

MacWorld [has an article](http://www.macworld.com/article/161065/2011/07/installing_lion_what_you_need_to_know.html) that outlines a few options you now have. Some users reported those as non-functional, while it [seemed to work](http://viktorpetersson.com/2011/07/20/how-to-upgrade-from-mac-os-x-lion-gm-to-final-release/) for others. Here's [yet another article](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/20/install-lion-final-release-over-lion-gm/) that confirms this procedure. Note that these are for the Golden Master versions and *not* the Developer Previews, so they might not work as well.

- Delete the version you're running and start with a new installation
- <kbd>Option</kbd>-click the "Buy"-button in the App Store
- <kbd>Option</kbd>-click the "Purchases"-button in the App Store's main window
- Hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key while you start the App Store

Comment: @masedesign Out of curiosity -- which one worked out for you in the end? (If at all...)